# Basic Footer issue

Tags: jquery, footer

I want a footer that is anchored at the bottom of the PAGE not always anchored at the bottom of the browser window all the time.

My homepage features a long vertical page using an auto scroller (by clicking a button), and also sandbox sort plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/ZkKys/4/ Since I use the sort feature, the height changes on which sort option you choose.

I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the page, but not be sticky. Then on other pages where they are significantly shorter, I still want the footer to rest at the bottom of the page, but not be sticky.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Please add tags for the relevant technology you use, "footer" by itself is useless. And please post the _relevant_ code inline in your question (use the "edit" button to ad it in). A jsfiddle link is fine to illustrate, but your question needs to stand by itself without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the page, but not be sticky" but have you tried this resource?

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

your css positioning will determine how your footer is "stuck" to the bottom of the page. Using position: fixed or depending on other css, position: absolute will keep it at the bottom of the window no matter where the user is on the page. But that sounds like what you don't want, so try the above link and see if that works for you.